# Im manually changing value and color of a cell, i want same value and color to be replicated into a cell another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Im manually changing value and color of a cell, i want same value and color to be replicated into a cell another sheet on the same time. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

value is easy. Just put =A1 into the other cell. For formatting changes, you will need VBA, for example

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' when a cell in column A is changed,
' the change will be copied to column F

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Copy Target.Offset(0, 5)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End Sub
```

Note that this code will copy the format and the value, but it will only run automatically when a cell is edited, not when a cell is only formatted. There is no event that can pick up format changes.